# Progress bar not being updated in a separate form using BackgroundWorker C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I was accessing DB in button click event in **Main UI**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    // sample query
    string strSQL_Query = "SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM Employees";
    SqlCommand cmd_QueryLength = new SqlCommand(strSQL_Query, con);
    DataTable dt_Query = new DataTable();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();

    dt_Query.Load(cmd_QueryLength.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();

    // Do some work
}
```

Now I want to show progress bar while data is fetched from DB so I placed DB access code in

```
private void backgroundWorker_start_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);

    // sample query
    string strSQL_Query = "SELECT COUNT(EmployeeID) FROM Employees";
    SqlCommand cmd_QueryLength = new SqlCommand(strSQL_Query, con);
    DataTable dt_Query = new DataTable();

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        con.Open();

    dt_Query.Load(cmd_QueryLength.ExecuteReader());
    con.Close();

    // Do some work
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        backgroundWorker_start.ReportProgress(i);

    // Do some more work
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        backgroundWorker_start.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

And I updated my click event as following.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    progressBarStart = new ProgressBar();
    backgroundWorker_start = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker_start.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker_start.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_start_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker_start.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_start_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker_start.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_start_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundWorker_start.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_start_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBarStart.Dispose();
}

void backgroundWorker_start_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{        
    progressBarStart.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

**[UPDATE]** My code is getting in to backgroundWorker_start_DoWork and completing my task however I can not see any progress in progress bar. Do I need to update ProgressBar UI or is there something else I need to see.

**Progress Bar UI**   Form contains a progress bar

```
public partial class ProgressBar: Form
{
    public ProgressBar()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();        
    }
}
```

Comment: *when I click button it is not getting to DB access code* - because there is no db calls whatsoever in the code. Or you forgot to post it.

Comment: Its really confusing, I don't see any DB access code in your updated button click event...

Comment: @Sinatr DB access code added, however my question was from Button Click event when I moved my code in backgroundWorker_start_DoWork, then ackgroundWorker_start_DoWork is not working, is it something to do with firing of backgroundWorker_start_DoWork?? OR I am doing something wrong

Comment: shouldn't the background worker be created outside the Click() event handler? and only RunWorkerAsync() called there? otherwise the backgroudworker object will be disposed after leaving the click handler?

Comment: This code needs a lot of work.  But starting point is that you *must* check e.Error in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler so errors don't just disappear without trace.  Debug the exception with Debug > Exceptions > tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Comment: @PiotrPiotr This is my first attempt to work with Backgroundworker and Progress bar.So you think I should place it outside of Click event?

Comment: @Basit - yes, this is the way MSDN says should be done. You may refer to this description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When button is clicked you create `BackgroundWorker`, properly initialize it and start. Put breakpoint inside `backgroundWorker_start_DoWork` to see it.

What you did wrong is what

```
// Do some work
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    backgroundWorker_start.ReportProgress(i);
```

doesn't actually do anything and `BackgroundWorker` finishes immediately.

What you have to do: split your work into peaces, and report progress after each peace is completed. Try

```
// Do some work
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    backgroundWorker_start.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

to actually see something happening.

Comment: Thanks, I get to this point where after performing task I am able to get in backgroundWorker_start.ReportProgress(i);
However I am still unable to see Progress Bar even though loop is wokring fine and moving to other piece of code